# Bubble Shooter, Drawing Bubbles

Tags: java, swing, awt

I try to make a bubble shooter game and I have problem with drawing bubbles on MyPanel which extend JPanel. Class bubble(extend JButton) has method paintComponent:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    RenderingHints qualityHints = new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    qualityHints.put(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
    g2d.setRenderingHints(qualityHints);
    g2d.setColor(c);
    g2d.fillOval(this.x,this.y,this.r, this.r);
}
```

How I should make constructor of MyPanel and method paint(); in MyPanel class, if I want to display Bubbles in 20 columns, 10 rows?

Comment: This may help you.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29947016/problems-with-detecting-mouseclick-in-a-jpanel-and-preventing-circle-from-painti/

Comment: *"Class bubble(extend JButton).."*  That's where it starts to go wrong.  `Bubble` should not extend anything, but have a `draw(Graphics)` method that knows where and how to draw each bubble.

Comment: You woulds also need some for loops to create this bubble grid with specific offsets to create the interweaving bubbles (much like an Isometric game grid), I recommend starting here:

ISOMETRICS:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/892811/drawing-isometric-game-worlds.

Hexagons/Isometrics:

http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/game-programming/isometric-n-hexagonal-maps-part-i-r747

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are struggling with these bubbles for some time now: [Bubble shooter game on Graphics2D, only one bubble display [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29866365/bubble-shooter-game-on-graphics2d-only-one-bubble-display) and [Painting balloons on Graphics2D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29865305/painting-balloons-on-graphics2d) appear to be about similar problems. Please include your previous code and/or links to your related questions when you ask a new question.

A custom panel for the bubbles could look like this:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class BubblePanel extends JPanel {
    private final List<Bubble> bubbles;

    public BubblePanel() {
        bubbles = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < 10; rowIndex++)
            for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < 20; columnIndex++)
                bubbles.add(new Bubble(100 + columnIndex * 60, 100 + rowIndex * 60,
                            28, Color.YELLOW));
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        for (final Bubble bubble : bubbles)
            bubble.paintComponent(g);
    }
}
```

Note: as [camickr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/131872/camickr) already wrote in [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29866944/1694043) to one of your previous questions, with Swing you override the `paintComponent` method to implement your own custom painting. You can read more about this topic in the official Java lesson about [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html). The `paintComponent` method is introduced in step 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `GridBagLayout()`. You can easily manage columns and rows using `GridBagConstraints`. To know more about `GridBagLayout()` checkout the documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html).